# How to clean up GIT conflicts to one users' version ignoring the rest

Tags: eclipse, git

We have two developers working on a project using GIT.

Now we have one version with user A where everything is OK and user B made modifications that all can be ignored.

However user A and user B committed the changes...

How can we reset the sitaution so that we just use users' A version and all user B changes are ignored?

We are working on Android project using Eclipse and are new to GIT...

Comment: Your question isn't really amazingly clear I tried my best at understanding it. Mainly lacks info about how you use git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User A-> C1--C3--C4--C5--C6--C7--C2&7
                \              /
                 User B->C1--C2
```

From your question I get that you want to go back to C3 ? If so you can get the SHA of C3 and then do a `git reset SHAofC3`

But in any case for going back to a specific commit you will always want to `git reset (--hard|--mixed|--soft) CommitSHA`. While `--hard` will clear out all changes `--soft` and `--mixed` will only rewind the commits but won't erase the changes.

While the above will cause a non-ff so if you are pushing to a public repository you should consider `git revert SHAofCommit` which will create a commit that reverts all changes done by that commit.

Comment: thank you very much. Actually the commits are quite mixed and again all we need is the complete version of one user ignoring all commits. So what we ended up doing is deleting all of user's B project and local repository and recreated a new one from user A. But thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

From the sound of it you're all committing to the same remote repository, and probably directly to `master`. So I'll assume your history looks like:

```
A1    B1    A2    A3    B2
o-----o-----o-----o-----o
```

You'll have to `revert` the changes committed by user B:

```
git revert <hash>
```

Which will add an additional commit for each revert:

```
A1    B1    A2    A3    B2    B1r   B2r
o-----o-----o-----o-----o-----o-----o
```

If there are multiple branches on remote, let me know and I'll update with those specifics.

Side note: If all your developers are committing to the same remote repository then you're using `git` like `svn`. Each developer should have their own remote as well, to which they can `commit`, `branch`, etc. Then when a change-set is approved it is merged into the central repo.

Comment: many thanks - but we just recreated the complete local repositiry from user A's clean version so that user B starts from there again